# Why can women be lashed if Deuteronomy 25:3 speaks in masculine terms ("then thy brother should be dishonoured before thine eyes")?

Tags: halacha, talmud-gemara, torah-study, lashes-malkos

According to [Deuteronomy 25:3](https://mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt0525.htm):

> ג  אַרְבָּעִים יַכֶּנּוּ, לֹא יֹסִיף:  פֶּן-יֹסִיף לְהַכֹּתוֹ עַל-אֵלֶּה מַכָּה רַבָּה, וְנִקְלָה אָחִיךָ לְעֵינֶיךָ.

> Forty stripes he may give him, he shall not exceed; lest, if he should exceed, and beat him above these with many stripes, then thy brother should be dishonoured before thine eyes.

Since the word used here means essentially "brother" ([אָחִ֖יךָ](https://biblehub.com/text/deuteronomy/25-3.htm)), which seems to be used [mainly in masculine contexts](https://biblehub.com/hebrew/achicha_251.htm) (although some translations use the word ["peer"](https://www.sefaria.org/Deuteronomy.25.3?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en), instead of "brother" which is a little strange given that according to the [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D7%90%D7%97%D7%99%D7%9A), the word being used here is a singular form of אָח‎ (ách)‎ with second-person masculine singular personal pronoun as possessor), how appropriate is it to prescribe the punishment of lashing to a woman? For instance why do the lashes apply to women in the case of a woman wearing a man's garb? You can see this being applied to women in both [Mishna Makkos 3:14](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishnah_Makkot.3.14?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) and [Maimonedes too lists them](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishneh_Torah%2C_The_Sanhedrin_and_the_Penalties_within_their_Jurisdiction.18.1?lang=bi), but if the verse is speaking about your brother, why are they also applied to women? How do the Rabbis understand this?

Comment: This question seems to be a subset of "[Confused about the proper punishment for lesbianism since num. '40' is often symbolic & the use of the word "brother" (אָחִ֖יךָ) for a woman is odd?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/134825/1368)", by the same author.

Comment: @TamirEvan Yeah, the person who replied to me told me to ask it as a separate question since it'd be more appropriate. I hope that that's not a problem.

Comment: Yes, this is a precise, direct, answer-able question. Thank you for breaking it out.